# How to Trap an Outlook 2013 Task Completed without Custom Form Scripts

Tags: vba, outlook, task

We have [Outlook 2013 which now comes with Custom Form Script disabled](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/custom-form-script-is-now-disabled-by-default-bd8ea308-733f-4728-bfcc-d7cce0120e94) and we can't re-enable it (company policy). Normal VBA works fine.

I need to send an email when a task is marked as complete. How can I get notified when the task is marked complete so I can send the email? I can use any of the standard Application Events, but none seem to help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Items.ItemChange` event on the Tasks folder (whcih can be retrieved using `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)`).

Comment: So far, so good. Looks like a good solution. Learning more about Outlook programming every day.

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Having used the guidance that Dmitry Streblechenko gave, this is the code that works. Posting for completeness.

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.taskitem
    If Item.Class = olTask Then
        If Item.Complete Then
            'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties
            Dim objMail As Outlook.mailItem
            Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            With objMail
                .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                .To = ""
                .CC = ""
                .HTMLBody = "Stuff"
                .Display
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope that helps others wanting to do the same.